# SQL Trigger is not working properly because of 'invalid trigger specification'

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

I'm working on a table called `Employees` where `first_name` and `last_name` are stored (as varchar). I created the trigger below to check if a combination of the first and last name already exists:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER VALIDATE_NAME 
BEFORE INSERT ON EMPLOYEES 
IF (SELECT count(*) FROM employees 
     WHERE firs_name = new.first_name AND LAST_NAME = new.last_name) = 0
  BEGIN
  END
ELSE IF (SELECT count(*) FROM employees
          WHERE firs_name = new.first_name AND LAST_NAME = new.last_name) >= 1
  BEGIN
    RETURN FALSE;
  END;
```

However I receive an error message `Invalid trigger specification`, which I don't understand. Could someone clarify what I'm doing wrong? I have removed the content of the first `BEGIN/END` as it just stores the new information like it is supposed to.

P.S.: This is for a theoretical case studie, I know the proper way to check for duplicate entries is not using first and last name as two people may share the same name. I know that, so please don't start about it :-)

Comment: Which dbms? (You code isn't ANSI SQL...)

Comment: I should have clarrified @jarlh, I'm using Oracle with SQL Developer

Comment: I added the tag as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your trigger in its current form doesn't make much sense. A trigger is not a function, so you cannot return a value from it.

Also, your trigger is not a row-level trigger, but a statement-level one, so you cannot reference the new values (since your trigger is fired once per *statement*, not per *row*) - a row-level trigger has to be declared as `FOR EACH ROW`.

The proper way to ensure uniqueness is not a trigger, but a UNIQUE constraint (see [AskTom on using triggers](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2008/08-sep/o58asktom-101055.html)) :

```
ALTER TABLE employees ADD CONSTRAINT employees_name_uq UNIQUE(firstname, lastname);
```

Comment: I've changed it to a row-level trigger (as I need to validate new inputs). I have to use a trigger for this case, so I cannot use a constraint like that unfortunately.

Comment: @KevinVoorn Fair enough, but please read the link in my updated answer and make sure you fully understand the implications of using triggers for enforcing business constraints.

Comment: I've read it, interesting article for sure! I will mark your answer as accepted as it does solve the problem for other users who might have this problem, I will continue to try and search for a solution that does involve triggers anyway. But thanks for your insights!